# Tannakian theory for Lie algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, algebraic-groups, geometric-representation-theory, tannakian-category

Let $G$ be a reductive (just in case) linear algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the Lie algebra of $G$. Consider the category $\operatorname{Rep}(G)$ of finite dimensional representations of $G$. Let $F\colon \operatorname{Rep}(G) \rightarrow \operatorname{Vect}_{\mathbb{C}}$ be the forgetfull (fiber) functor. According to the Tannkian formalism, group $G$ coincides with the group of tensor authomorphisms of the functor $F$.

Is it true that the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is nothing else but the Lie algebra of endomorphisms $E\colon F \rightarrow F $ such that for any two representations $V,W \in \operatorname{Rep}(G)$ the following map
$ F(V) \otimes F(W) \xrightarrow{E(V)\otimes \operatorname{Id} + \operatorname{Id} \otimes E(W)} F(V)\otimes F(W)
$
coincides with the map $F(V\otimes W) \xrightarrow{E(V\otimes W)} F(V\otimes W)$
with respect to the identification $F(V)\otimes F(W) \simeq F(V\otimes W)$?

Comment: [This question also appears on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2936876/tannakian-theory-for-lie-algebras/2938112) (I posted an answer there).